# Есть коллекция элементов, надо применить стили по клик на иконку к тому div на который кликаю

Tags: javascript

У меня есть  одинаковых 8 дивов на странице. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы по клику на иконку (круговая стрелка) карточка поворачивалась. Я реализовала это с помощью переключателя классов. Но беда в том, что я смогла найти решение только поставив слушатель событий на всю карточку. А мне надо, чтобы слушатель событий стоял только на иконке. При этом чтобы переключатель классов срабатывал только на том блоке, на котором срабатывает клик по иконке.
Вот что у меня есть на данный момент.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', function() {
  item.querySelector('.front').classList.toggle('front_rotate');
  item.querySelector('.back').classList.toggle('back_rotate');
}));
```

```css
.front {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 0;
}

.front_rotate {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back_rotate {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.img-style {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 90px;
}

.img-position img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.card-text,
.back-text {
  width: 84%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.btn-card-text {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.back_arrow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin: 8% 5% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card style-element" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="./img/foto.png" class="card-img-top img-style" alt="#">
    <div class="card-body">
      <input class="card-text" placeholder="&#9998">
      <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
      <p class="out-front">яблоко</p>
      <div class="img-position">
        <img src="./img/down.png" alt="#">
        <img src="./img/repost.png" alt="#">
        <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#">
        <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="#" class="arrow_card">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <input type="text" class="back-text" placeholder="&#9998">
    <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
    <p id="out">Тут будет текст который ввели</p>
    <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_card back_arrow">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="card style-element" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="./img/foto.png" class="card-img-top img-style" alt="#">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input class="card-text" placeholder="&#9998">
        <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
        <p class="out-front">ананас</p>
        <div class="img-position">
          <img src="./img/down.png" alt="#">
          <img src="./img/repost.png" alt="#">
          <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#">
          <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="#" class="arrow_card">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <input type="text" class="back-text" placeholder="&#9998">
      <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
      <p id="out">Тут будет текст который ввели</p>
      <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_card back_arrow">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="card style-element" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="./img/foto.png" class="card-img-top img-style" alt="#">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input class="card-text" placeholder="&#9998">
        <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
        <p class="out-front">Тут уже ввели название карточки</p>
        <div class="img-position">
          <img src="./img/down.png" alt="#">
          <img src="./img/repost.png" alt="#">
          <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#">
          <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="#" class="arrow_card">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <input type="text" class="back-text" placeholder="&#9998">
      <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
      <p id="out">Тут будет текст который ввели</p>
      <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_card back_arrow">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то так:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.arrow_card').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let card = this.closest('.card');
    card.querySelector('.front').classList.toggle('front_rotate');
    card.querySelector('.back').classList.toggle('back_rotate');
  });
});
```

```css
.front{
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.front, .back{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 0;
}

.front_rotate  {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back_rotate{
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.img-style{
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 90px;
}

.img-position img{   
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.card-text, .back-text{
  width: 84%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.btn-card-text{
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
  background:#f8f9fa;
}

.back_arrow{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin: 8% 5% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card style-element" style="width: 18rem;">
   <div class="front">
      <img src="./img/foto.png" class="card-img-top img-style" alt="#">
      <div class="card-body">
         <input class="card-text" placeholder="&#9998">
         <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
         <p class="out-front">яблоко</p>
         <div class="img-position">
            <img src="./img/down.png" alt="#">
            <img src="./img/repost.png" alt="#">
            <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#">
            <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-curved-arrow-icon-2261-thumb.png" alt="#" class="arrow_card">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="back">
      <input type="text" class="back-text" placeholder="&#9998">
      <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
      <p id="out">Тут будет текст который ввели</p>
      <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-curved-arrow-icon-2261-thumb.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_card back_arrow">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
   <div class="card style-element" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="front">
         <img src="./img/foto.png" class="card-img-top img-style" alt="#">
         <div class="card-body">
            <input class="card-text" placeholder="&#9998">
            <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
            <p class="out-front">ананас</p>
            <div class="img-position">
               <img src="./img/down.png" alt="#">
               <img src="./img/repost.png" alt="#">
               <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#">
               <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-curved-arrow-icon-2261-thumb.png" alt="#" class="arrow_card">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
         <input type="text" class="back-text" placeholder="&#9998">
         <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
         <p id="out">Тут будет текст который ввели</p>
         <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-curved-arrow-icon-2261-thumb.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_card back_arrow">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
   <div class="card style-element" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="front">
         <img src="./img/foto.png" class="card-img-top img-style" alt="#">
         <div class="card-body">
            <input class="card-text" placeholder="&#9998">
            <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
            <p class="out-front">Тут уже ввели название карточки</p>
            <div class="img-position">
               <img src="./img/down.png" alt="#">
               <img src="./img/repost.png" alt="#">
               <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#">
               <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-curved-arrow-icon-2261-thumb.png" alt="#" class="arrow_card">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
         <input type="text" class="back-text" placeholder="&#9998">
         <button class="btn-card-text">ok</button>
         <p id="out">Тут будет текст который ввели</p>
         <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-curved-arrow-icon-2261-thumb.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_card back_arrow">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! я уже несколько дней бьюсь над этой задачей. все сработало! еще раз спасибо!